# Jenkins Pipeline publish over cifs with pyinstaller generated file not copying over

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins pipeline which checks out some python code then does a pyinstaller to create an executable. By default I see this is in the dist folder.

However when I try and copy anything from this folder across to a SMB share via the Publish over CIFS plugin it does not copy. I have tried multiple different syntaxes for source and remote destinations but no luck.

Here is a sample of the pipeline:

```
pipeline {
agent any
stages {
stage('Build') {
  steps {
    sh 'python -m py_compile main.py test.py'
  }
}
stage('Create Installer') {
  steps {
    sh 'pyinstaller --onefile main.py'
  }
}
stage('Delivery') {
  parallel {
    stage('Delivery') {
      steps {
        cifsPublisher(publishers: [[configName: 'test', transfers: [[cleanRemote: true, excludes: '', flatten: false, makeEmptyDirs: false, noDefaultExcludes: false, patternSeparator: '', remoteDirectory: '', remoteDirectorySDF: false, removePrefix: '', sourceFiles: 'dist/*.*']], usePromotionTimestamp: false, useWorkspaceInPromotion: false, verbose: true]])
      }
    }
    stage('Echo') {
      steps {
        sh 'pwd'
      }
    }
  }
}
stage('Archive Artifacts') {
  steps {
    archiveArtifacts 'dist/main'
  }
}
```

}
}

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I've problem using wildcards for `sourceFiles` too. Have you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your example, it is helpful. I succeed with the param below. You need to add a cifs config named NAS first:

```
cifsPublisher(publishers: [[configName: 'NAS', transfers: [[cleanRemote: false, excludes: '', flatten: false, makeEmptyDirs: false, noDefaultExcludes: false, patternSeparator: '', remoteDirectory: "/build/TempBuild/${git_branch}/${str}", remoteDirectorySDF: false, removePrefix: '', sourceFiles: '*.tar']], usePromotionTimestamp: false, useWorkspaceInPromotion: false, verbose: true]])
```